# Convergent or divergent series ? Given that $\sum a_n $ is already convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Could anyone please give me some hints ?

Let $\sum a_n$ be a convergent serie of real number. Prove or disprove that $\sum a_n \sin n$ and $\sum n^{\frac{1}{n}} a_n$ are also convergent.

Comment: 1. Try to play with sign of $\sin n$ and relatively convergence series.

Comment: @mvggz This argument works if $a_n\ge0$.

Comment: @ Julián Aguirre, indeed.. I have written that too quickly sorry

Answer (score 1):

For the first one consider $\sum\sin n/n$. It converges by Dirichlet's test, but $\sum\sin^2n/n$ diverges (hint:$2\,\sin^2n=1-\cos(2\,n)$.)

For the second one use Abe's test ($n^{1/n}$ is monotone and bounded.)